# Install Neo4j on Azure, cannot browse WebAdmin

Tags: azure, neo4j

I've just installed Neo4j 1.8.2 onto Azure by following this step-by-step process...

http://de.slideshare.net/neo4j/neo4j-on-azure-step-by-step-22598695

Unfortunately, when I browse to http://:7474/webadmin Fiddler says Error 10061 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I've followed the instructions exactly and haven't received any errors.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is your url something like `http://servicename.cloudapp.net:7474`? Hard to tell from your question - may be a typo.

Comment: Hi David, yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think I got to the bottom of this. I think it was due to the size of compute / VM I was creating. It looks like the problem is caused when running on Extra Small instances. I created a new installation using a Small instance and everything now works :).

Comment: Wow - I wasn't expecting that. I'll have to poke around the as-is config setting for the VMDepot image for assumed memory consumption. I've never tried running it in XS.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the server to accept connections form all hosts, and maybe use a newer Neo4j, say 1.9.4

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_secure_the_port_and_remote_client_connection_accepts

Comment: The VM Depot pre-built image is already set up for all-hosts and service auto-start. I suspect it's related to a bad URL being specified, or external endpoint not set up properly...

Comment: Is there a VM Depot image for 1.9.4 or even 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

The way the VM Depot image is set up, it's pre-configured to allow all hosts to connect, and the Neo4j server will auto-start. The only thing *you* need to take care of, when constructing your VM, is to open an **Input Endpoint**, with any public port you want (preferably 7474 to stay true to Neo4j) and internal port 7474.

Note that the UI changed a bit since the how-to was published: You can specify the endpoint as the last step before creating your virtual machine. Other than that, the instructions should be the same. And... once the VM is up and running (it'll take about 5-10 minutes), you just visit `http://yourservicename.cloudapp.net:7474` and you should see the web admin. Note: this is *not* the same as your *vm name*. If you named your VM something like 'neo' then you do *not* want `http://neo:7474` or `http://neo.cloudapp.net:7474`. You need to use your cloud service name (you had to create a name for the service when you deployed the VM.

I've deployed that image several times in demos, and just tried again right now to make sure nothing wonky happened. Worked perfectly.